# XML Stream returning zero rows

Tags: c#, xml

I have a text string containing XML data (though it has no header info) and I am attempting to populate a DataTable containing its elements. I am not receiving any error messages, however my DataTable contains 0 rows following the .ReadXml command. The Xml is as follows:

```
<items>
 <item>
  <Date>05-Feb-2008</Date>
  <User>Unknown</User>
  <Comment>Due date moved</Comment>
  <Restricted>True</Restricted>
 </item>
 <item>
  <Date>07-Nov-2008</Date>
  <User>Unknown</User>
  <Comment>Priority increased. Due date moved to end Oct</Comment>
  <Restricted>False</Restricted>
 </item>
</items>
```

And my code to create the DataTable is as follows:

```
Stream xmlStream = new MemoryStream();
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(xmlStream);
string xml = (string)row["XmlComments"];
writer.Write(xml);
writer.Flush();
xmlStream.Position = 0;

DataTable xmlComments = new DataTable();

xmlComments.Columns.Add("User", typeof(string));
xmlComments.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));
xmlComments.Columns.Add("Comment", typeof(string));
xmlComments.Columns.Add("OSG_Only", typeof(string));

xmlComments.ReadXml(xmlStream);
```

Could anyone shed any light on what I'm missing here?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
DataTable xmlComments = new DataTable();

xmlComments.TableName = "item"; //<---- Added
xmlComments.Columns.Add("User", typeof(string));
xmlComments.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(string)); //<---- Type changed
xmlComments.Columns.Add("Comment", typeof(string));
xmlComments.Columns.Add("Restricted", typeof(string)); //<---- Column name changed

xmlComments.ReadXml(xmlStream);
```

Comment: Fantastic, that's fixed it. I was wondering if I needed to specify "item" somewhere, I probably should have tried that before posting. Also, the field is really called "OSG_Only" I just tried and failed to remove the reference to it from my post!! Many thanks for your help